# Weekly rankings issue

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I'm looking at the weekly rankings

[image]

And I notice that my reputation is higher than Tim Schmelter's for the week and JB Nizet, however they appear +1/+2 in front of me?

Unless my math is wrong, 1,246 > 1,234

Should I not be placed where JB Nizel is?

Comment: Caching. The order is cached, it'll right itself soon.

Comment: My money's on caching.  But we should definitely look into that "math" thing, just to be sure.  ;)

Comment: Note that Gordon Linoff at the top managed to pass by BalusC as well, but is in the 'incorrect' place in your screenshot still. In any case, I see you listed in the 'correct' place when visiting the users list now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - yeah I noticed that too.  Thanks :)